# How to add programmatically TextView in current layout

Tags: java, android

I want to add programmatically a TextView in current view. I know how to make it when I create a new layout but I want to add this to current layout, the main problem is how to get reference to main_activity layout.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: put your code here

Comment: M.Tarek I saw this post but when I want to remake this I had no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have a `LinearLayout` in your project like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

To add many `TextView's` in your layout, you can do something like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.main);


        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
        valueTV.setId(5);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
    }
}
```

Comment: as I understand this code add text view to a new linearLayout. I want to add a textView to this setContentView(R.layout.main); I created main aplication view and inside onCreate I have condition that check variable and if true add an extra textView to current view

Comment: is the same thing bro, you can find your layout, and  add your TextView on it.  I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly :) tell me every layout or button  etc. inherit after View? Such as in java String, Integer etc. inherit after Object?

Comment: Yes, with one exception, layout managers like Relative Layout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout inherit from ViewGroup and the ViewGroup class inherit after View :D
Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Probably I spoil something.  When I want to find layout View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.activity_main); I don't have access to activity_main, but when I try something like that View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.layout.activity_main); it's forbidden action. Shoul I add main_activity code?

Answer (score -1):

```
private boolean tuVariable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.completar_perfil);
        if(tuVariable){ //si tu variable es true
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText("you message");
        }
```